# How do i fix my dropping problem in C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, game-physics

I have problem with pictrure box in this project. When form is loaded my character is devided to two sides and started bugging under the other picture box, but my other mario on the grass can jump and move normally. It just look like my game bugging and i dont know how to repair it. Sorry for my English, it is not my mother language and i have problem with it sometimes :)

I dont try anything i just dont know how to repair it. My expectections are my character doesnt drop to the other picture box and just stay on the other picture box
The characters name is "pbMario" and the other picture boxs name is "Podlaha"
There is my code to character stay on the other picture box:

```
     if (pbMario.Bottom > Podlaha.Top)
     {
         pbMario.Top = Podlaha.Top - pbMario.Height;
         skok = false;
                
     }
        Gravity: skok = true;
                 force = gravity;

       int force;
        int gravity = 15;


       pbMario.Top -= force;
       force--;
```

!The skok variable is like jump bool!

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] code in the question accordingly. Note that you are not required (and not even expected) to post actual code (unlike [CodeReview.se]), but rather example that demonstrates the problem - so instead of "The skok variable is like jump bool" comment just rename variables.